# Email sender namespace reference for a .Net Core framework ASP.Net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an email sender working as shown below for a C# Console App with .Net Framework 4.6.1 as target framework for the application. However I have tried to reuse the code in a C# ASP.Net web project with .Net Core 1.0 as target framework but the namespace System.Net.Mail is not available in .Core framework.

Which  reference does one add in a in a C# ASP.Net web project with .Net Core 1.0 so that email_sender is reusable? Alternatively is there reference to use for .Net Core 1.0 to send an email?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

private static void email_sender()
{
    string filename = @"<attachment path>";
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mainserver.domain.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("from@fromdomain.com");
    mail.To.Add("receiver@domain.com");
    mail.Subject = "Email subject";
    mail.Body = "Report";
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(filename);
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    SmtpServer.Port = 25;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: `System.Net.Mail` is not available in .NET Core 1.0, see https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/08/20/sending-email-net-core-2-0/

Comment: The [documentation of SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) warns that this class is obsolete and `strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use that class. The documentation itself warns that it's obsolete and "strongly recommends" people use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) or MimeKit. It even emits a compilation warning about this.

The latest [MailKit version on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) is 2.06 and targets .NET Standard 1.3, 1.6 and 2.0 which means it can be used with any .NET Core version. If you check the [project's Github Repo](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) you'll see it provides a *lot* of email features that aren't available with System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, like sending MIME messages, HTML bodies, etc.

For easy migration, MailKit allows explicitly casting a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage to a MimeMessage class. As a first step you could use the MailMessage code you already have and only change the SmtpClient-related code :

```
        using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient ()) {
            client.Connect ("mainserver.domain.com", 25, false);
            // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
            client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

            var message=(MimeMessage)mail;

            client.Send (message);
            client.Disconnect (true);
        }
```

The docs show how to [create more complex messages](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm#CreateMessageWithAttachments), attach images, files etc using MimeMessage directly.

The example in docs shows how to construct a message with embedded images, an HTML body and attachtments. This simplified example shows only what's needed to add an attachment :

```
        var message = new MimeMessage ();
        message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joey", "joey@friends.com"));
        message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Alice", "alice@wonderland.com"));
        message.Subject = "How you doin?";

        var builder = new BodyBuilder ();

        // Set the plain-text version of the message text
        builder.TextBody = @"Hey Alice,... ";

        // We may also want to attach a calendar event for Monica's party...
        builder.Attachments.Add (@"C:\Users\Joey\Documents\party.ics");

        // Now we just need to set the message body and we're done
        message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody ();
```